# Docker OCI runtime create failure

Tags: docker

When I run "docker run -it python:3" in a Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS server, I got the following error.  What does this mean and how do I fix this?

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:385: running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"fork/exec /usr/bin/dockerd (deleted): no such file or directory\\\"\"": unknown.
```

Comment: What does `docker info` show? Also `systemctl status docker`.

Comment: Never mind.. I just reinstalled docker and it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

> Restart docker service.

I was also facing same issue.  Solve it by restarting docker service:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Same described here,
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29640#issuecomment-273617532

Comment: This solution does not work for me neither does the snap version... Any ideas? I'm using the snap if that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who might have installed using `snap`, this will restart all docker services:

```
sudo snap restart docker
```

Or, for just the daemon, use:

```
sudo snap restart docker.dockerd
```